# Composer : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, composer-php

I'm using symfony for a web app and I need to require packages with composer `composer require` I have this error
`curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

I already downloaded the cacert.pem file, placed it in my php folder and edited this line in my php.ini : `;curl.cainfo = "C:\Program Files\PHP\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"` but it didn't changed anything.

Did someone know how i can solve it please ?

Comment: FYI: the semicolon `;` in front of an ini directive is commenting it out. this only to give you confirmation that it didn't change anything b/c only a comment has been added. Compare: **Example #2 _php.ini_ example** on https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php , for a short summary of the ini syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem by disable and enable again tls in composer with `composer config -g -- disable-tls true`